# Pushing out updates to multiple installs?

Tags: plugins, updates, installation

I'm planning on having many installations of wordpress on my server on different domains is there a way i can push updates out to all of them simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Use Git for your local installation ([example](http://wpkrauts.com/2014/test-multiple-wordpress-versions-with-one-installation/)). Then [create a `remote all` with multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785618/299509), one for each site.
When you want to update the sites, just type:

```
git push all --all
```